# How do you call msdeploy from powershell when the parameters have spaces?

Tags: iis, powershell, msdeploy

I'm running into a problem with spaces in my parameters that I try to send into msdeploy from a powershell script.

There are a number of other related articles but none of them solve the problem.

[Problems Using Power Shell And MSDeploy.](http://forums.iis.net/p/1163820/1929826.aspx#1929826)

Similar SO issue that doesn't work: [How to run exe in powershell with parameters with spaces and quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673967/how-to-run-exe-in-powershell-with-parameters-with-spaces-and-quotes)

**PowerShell BUG:** [Executing commands which require quotes and variables is practically impossible](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/376207/executing-commands-which-require-quotes-and-variables-is-practically-impossible)

Another SO issue that doesn't work:[Passing parameters in PowerShell 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773356/passing-parameters-in-powershell-2-0)

The simplest example that succeeds and then fails when I make it more complicated is just dumping the default web site.

$msdeploy = "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe"

&$msdeploy -verb:dump -source:appHostConfig=`'default web site`' -verbose


==SUCCESS

This one?

$sitename="default web site"

&$msdeploy -verb:dump -source:appHostConfig=$sitename -verbose


==FAIL with the following error

msdeploy.exe : Error: Unrecognized argument '"-source:"appHostConfig=default'. All arguments must begin with "-".

At C:\xxx\test.ps1:122 char:6

+     & 

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error: Unrecogn...begin with "-".:String) [], RemoteException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError


Error count: 1.

The following variations have also failed

#FAIL

$sitename=`'default web site`'

$sitename=`'"default web site"`'

$sitename="`'default web site`'"

$sitename="default web site"    

$sitename="'default web site'"

&$msdeploy -verb:dump "-source:appHostConfig=$sitename" -verbose

&$msdeploy -verb:dump -source:appHostConfig="$sitename" -verbose 

&$msdeploy -verb:dump -source:appHostConfig='$sitename' -verbose 

&$msdeploy -verb:dump -source:appHostConfig=`'$sitename`' -verbose 

&$msdeploy -verb:dump -source:appHostConfig=`"$sitename`" -verbose

I'm at a loss. Everyone I work with is at a loss. Seriously this sucks. I loved Powershell. I loved msdeploy. I can't say that I love putting them together. It looks like it may have been easier to focus on the API instead of the cli.

#### EDIT:

The parameters in the string array suggested by Emperor XLII works well. An alternative solution is presented in the following article: [The trials and tribulations of using MSDeploy with PowerShell](http://trycatchfail.com/blog/post/The-trials-and-tribulations-of-using-MSDeploy-with-PowerShell.aspx)

```
function PushToTarget([string]$server, [string]$remotePath, [string]$localPath) {
    cmd.exe /C $("msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:contentPath=`"{0}`" -dest:computerName=`"{1}`",contentPath=`"{2}`" -whatif" -f $localPath, $server, $remotePath )
}
```

Comment: Or consider using [Web Deploy PowerShell Cmdlets](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-powershell-cmdlets).

Comment: The Web Deploy PowerShell Cmdlets weren't available in 2010. The only option that the team provided was to use PowerShell to hit the .Net API directly. http://blogs.iis.net/jamescoo/archive/2009/09/09/cool-msdeploy-powershell-scripts.aspx   I don't think the cmd-lets got added until v3.

Comment: The article in your edit has a new URL: https://www.trycatchfail.com/2010/02/01/the-trials-and-tribulations-of-using-msdeploy-with-powershell/

Comment: @JulianM Web Deploy Powershell Cmdlets are woefully documented and, by searching, apparently unused industry wide. Not worth the time to figure it out.

Comment: Upgrading to latest Powershell version might help. See my sample code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56195230/3606250)

Comment: Maybe this is a duplicate of this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673967/how-to-run-an-exe-file-in-powershell-with-parameters-with-spaces-and-quotes/) which also discusses the general problem of passing spaces and quotes in Powershell arguments.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using the technique from [Keith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673967/how-to-run-exe-in-powershell-with-parameters-with-spaces-and-quotes/1674950#1674950) to [How to run exe in powershell with parameters with spaces and quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673967/how-to-run-exe-in-powershell-with-parameters-with-spaces-and-quotes) question you linked to, running `echoargs -verb:dump -source:appHostConfig=$sitename -verbose` gave me this output:

```
Arg 0 is <-verb:dump>
Arg 1 is <-source:appHostConfig=default>
Arg 2 is <web>
Arg 3 is <site>
Arg 4 is <-verbose>
```

This would explain the invalid argument of `appHostConfig=default` that `msdeploy` was seeing.

Running `echoargs -verb:dump "-source:appHostConfig=$sitename" -verbose`, with `$sitename = "default web site"`, appears to result in the desired arguments:

```
Arg 0 is <-verb:dump>
Arg 1 is <-source:appHostConfig=default web site>
Arg 2 is <-verbose>
```

Though from your list, it appears that this did not work for you.

Another method you might try is building up the list of arguments in an array, which powershell can automatically escape.  For example, this gives the same output as above:

```
[string[]]$msdeployArgs = @(
  "-verb:dump",
  "-source:appHostConfig=$sitename",
  "-verbose"
)
echoargs $msdeployArgs
```

Comment: After you posted your solution I was also pointed to this article: http://trycatchfail.com/blog/post/The-trials-and-tribulations-of-using-MSDeploy-with-PowerShell.aspx


Thanks for the help. Please up-vote the PowerShell parameter bug/defect listed above.

Comment: For those that might have missed it (took me a moment to find the mentioned link), here is the PowerShell connect bug: [Executing commands which require quotes and variables is practically impossible](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/376207/executing-commands-which-require-quotes-and-variables-is-practically-impossible)

Answer (score 10):

Just adding another way in case it is helpful to anyone:

```
Invoke-Expression "& '[path to msdeploy]\msdeploy.exe' --% -verb:sync -source:contentPath=`'$source`' -dest:contentPath=`'$dest`'"
```

"--%" is new to powershell 3. From [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2012/03/03/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters.aspx): "You simply add a the --% sequence (two dashes and a percent sign) anywhere in the command line and PowerShell will not try to parse the remainder of that line."

Comment: By far the easiest I've seen. Had me going in a minute flat.

Answer (score 7):

Found a working solution and easy fix.
Reference: http://answered.site/all-arguments-must-begin-with--at-cwindowsdtldownloadswebserviceswebservicesidservicepublishedwebsitesidservicedeploymentidservicewsdeployps123/4231580/

```
$msdeploy = "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe"
$msdeployArgs = @(
"-verb:sync",
"-source:iisApp='Default Web Site/HelloWorld'",
"-verbose",
"-dest:archiveDir='c:\temp1'"
)
Start-Process $msdeploy -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList $msdeployArgs
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Note that `Start-Process` does not set `$LASTEXITCODE`.  If you need to check the exit code, use the `-Wait` and `-PassThru` switches.  Then `Start-Process` returns a process object which has an `ExitCode` property.

Answer (score 6):

We had faced the similar kind of issue. Our fix was like below,

```
$path = "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe";

$verb = "-verb:sync";

$src = "-source:contentPath=[ESC][ESC][ESC]"c:\aa aa[ESC][ESC][ESC]";

$dest = "-dest:contentPath=[ESC][ESC][ESC]"c:\aa[ESC][ESC][ESC]";

Invoke-Expression "&'$path' $verb $src $dest";
```

where, <kbd>ESC</kbd> - is escape sequence/character

Comment: Instead of doing crazy things to highlight your code, use 4 spaces (check my edit).

Comment: This is the only thing that finally worked for me.  But I think you are missing a quote at the end of src and des     $src = "-source:contentPath=[ESC][ESC][ESC]"c:\aa aa[ESC][ESC][ESC]"";

Comment: I would also add that the [Esc] character for powershell is the ` character.  Not a single quote but the backward accent (usually paired with the tilde on your keyboard)

Answer (score 3):

I tried every technique under the sun, and this is the only one that worked for me (using PowerShell 2).

```
cmd.exe /C $("msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package=`"{0}`" -dest:auto,IncludeAcls=`"False`" -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:`"{1}`"" -f $mypackagepath, $myparamfilepath )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach derived from the input below.

```
$msdeploy = "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe";

$command = "-verb:sync";

$sourcePath = "C:\aa aa\";
$source = $("-source:contentPath=`"{0}`"" -f $sourcePath);

$destPath = "C:\aa"
$destination = $("-dest:contentPath=`"{0}`" -f $destPath);

$msdeploycommand = $("`"{0}`" {1} {2} {3} -verbose" -f $msdeploy, $command, $source, $destination);

cmd.exe /C "`"$msdeploycommand`"";
```

This caters for the MSDeploy.exe being in its default installation folder which contains spaces. Hence the wrapping with the escape character (`).

Answer (score 0):

I've used some ideas from answers above and came up with the following simpler function to do the thing.

Note that it is important to give the full path to MSDeploy as when running under the build agent it sometimes doesnt recognise the PATH to msdeploy.

```
function Deploy([string]$server, [string]$remotePath, [string]$localPath) {
        $msdeploy = "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe";
        cmd.exe /C $("`"{3}`" -verb:sync -source:contentPath=`"{0}`" -dest:computerName=`"{1}`",contentPath=`"{2}`" " -f $localPath, $server, $remotePath , $msdeploy )
    }
```

Usage

```
Deploy $hostName $remotePath $source
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the above did not work for me, this is the solution that worked:

```
# get msdeploy exe
$MSDeploy = ${env:ProgramFiles}, ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} |
        ForEach-Object {Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Filter 'MSDeploy.exe' -Recurse} |
        Sort-Object -Property @{Expression={[version]$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion}} -Descending |
        Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty FullName

#build deploy command        
$deplyCmd = """""$MSDeploy"" -verb:sync -dest:iisApp=""Default Web Site"" -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -source:iisApp=""$ExtraWebFilesFolder"""    

#execute    
&cmd /c $deplyCmd
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem has certainly been around for a long time and I spent some time battling it recently. The result has been successful for me so I'll post it here in hopes that it can help others who find this question in the future.

The first problem to resolve is getting rid of the spaces in the msdeploy path. There are two approaches here. One is persistent and requires you to have server access, the other is temporary in the context of your PowerShell script. Either will work but I'd prefer the first if it's an option for you.

For the first approach, create a junction point. Example script:

```
new-item -Path "c:\MS-WebDeploy" -ItemType Junction -Value "c:/Program Files (x86)/iis/microsoft web deploy v3"
```

For the second approach, create a PSDrive (w in this example)

```
New-PSDrive -Name "w" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "C:/Program Files (x86)/iis/microsoft web deploy v3"
```

I'm using three PowerShell variables below. For example purposes, pretend that all three have spaces.

- $ParamFilePath = "c:\deployment files\parameters.xml"
- $PackageName = "c:\deployment files\My Website.zip"
- $WebAppPath = "Default Web Site"

First, create an array and build up your arguments as needed.

```
#nothing needs to be done with these arguments so we'll start with them
[string[]]$arguments = @("-verb:sync", "-dest:auto", "-disableLink:AppPoolExtension", "-disableLink:ContentExtension", "-disableLink:CertificateExtension", "-allowUntrusted")

#double up on the quotes for these paths after the colon
$arguments += "-setParamFile:""$ParamFilePath"""
$arguments += "-source:package=""$PackageName"""

#must not have spaces with the commma, use single quotes on the name and value here
$arguments += "-setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='$WebAppPath'"

#add your own logic for optional arguments  
$arguments += "-EnableRule:EncryptWebConfig"
```

Now build the msdeploy command and put the PowerShell escape sequence to prevent PowerShell from "helping" later. Use the path you created with the junction or the PSDrive

```
$command = "w:\msdeploy.exe" + " --% " + $arguments -join " "
```

Finally, execute that command as a script block.

```
$sb = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock($command) 
& $sb
```

I've wrapped this and a bit more code into a script which is called like this.

```
.\Run-WebDeploy -WebAppPath "Default Web Site" -PackageName "c:\deployment files\My Website.zip"  -ParamFilePath "c:\deployment files\parameters.xml"  -EncryptWebConfig
```

In general, you can help yourself a lot by getting rid of the spaces in your paths/names. Sometimes, that can't be done and this should get you through.