# Commands executed in PowerShell with variables surrounded in quotes fail. Why?

Tags: powershell

I'm having a surprisingly difficult time embedding variables with quotes to an external command with PoSH. For example, this command

```
 dfsradmin membership list /rgname:`"stuff I want`"
```

gives me the following expected result:

```
 Failed:
 Replication group with name stuff I want cannot be found.
```

This command, however

```
 $group = "stuff I want"
 dfsradmin membership list /rgname:`"$group`"
```

fails with this error:

```
 Failed:
 The subobject "/rgname:"stuff is not a valid subobject.
```

Is this a bug with Powershell or am I missing/misunderstanding something?

Comment: It seems that with this particular command, there's no way to do it except by using cmd to write to a file and reading from it, i.e. the old-school way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to get around this by executing it in CMD.exe and doing string manipulations to get what I need.

```
$str = &cmd /c 'dfsradmin membership list /rgname:"blah blah"'
$str = &cmd /c "dfsradmin membership list /rgname:$blah"       # with vars
```

Thanks for the help! I hope this has been resolved in Powershell 3.0.

Comment: No, it hasn't been fixed in PowerShell 3.0 and to rub salt into the wounds, the native DFS-R PowerShell commands didn't make it into Windows 2012 but are coming in R2

Comment: I am very surprised at this considering that MS has been pushing DFSR hard for the last few years.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah there are known issues in Powershell ( including v2.0) around this:  http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/376207/executing-commands-which-require-quotes-and-variables-is-practically-impossible

See if the alternatives discussed in the link above work for you. I cannot try it out as I don't have that executable.

Also `echoargs.exe` is a useful tool that you can use to see what arguments have been recevied from Powershell.

Comment: Actually PowerShell performs automatic quoting in a way that works for 99+% of command-line tools. it appears that the `dfsradmin.exe` executable uses its own parser that doesn't work correctly with PowerShell's automatic quoting.

Answer (score 1):

I found that defining

```
$quote = '"'
```

and then using `/command$quote"test"$quote` works as well

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to add back ticks in front of quotes. Does this work for you?

```
 $group = "stuff I want"
 dfsradmin membership list /rgname:"$group"
```

Comment: Hi, Shay. It does not; I get the same error. I added the backticks to attempt at escaping the quotes.

Comment: @Shay - I don't see how this will work! And what is the difference from just using `$group` instead of `"$group"` in this case.

Comment: I can't test it but the quotes are needed if $group contain spaces and the underlying utility requires them.

Comment: Yeah, but that is when you say `"stuff I want"` and not when you use `$group` right?

Comment: @Carlos Can you provide a sample command that works in cmd.exe?

Comment: @Shay: Here's an example: `$directory = "C:\windows\system32"; cacls "$directory"`

Comment: @Carlos your example seems to be working for me, I get the ACLs output of $directory.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround which doesn't call cmd but uses Invoke-Expression instead. The command has to be put in a variable first:

$var = "string with spaces"

$command = "first part " + [char]96 + [char]34 + $var + [char]96 + [char]34 + " second part"

Invoke-Expression $command

Not that pretty but it works. You can replace [char]96 with '`' and [char]34 with '"' if you prefer. Easy to create a function which does it if you use it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above did not work for me but based on Carlos idea, this is the solution that worked posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499699/how-do-you-call-msdeploy-from-powershell-when-the-parameters-have-spaces/46487982#46487982)

```
# get msdeploy exe
$MSDeploy = ${env:ProgramFiles}, ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} |
        ForEach-Object {Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Filter 'MSDeploy.exe' -Recurse} |
        Sort-Object -Property @{Expression={[version]$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion}} -Descending |
        Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty FullName

#build deploy command        
$deplyCmd = """""$MSDeploy"" -verb:sync -dest:iisApp=""Default Web Site"" -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -source:iisApp=""$ExtraWebFilesFolder"""    

#execute    
&cmd /c $deplyCmd
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old thread but just posting here in case my solution works for somebody as it worked for me.
This particular command (dfsradmin) expects natively seen quotes so I just enclosed value with **quotes** in **single quotes** thus passing quotes as well:

```
   dfsradmin membership list /rgname:'"stuff I want"'
```

or if using through variable:

```
    $group = '"stuff I want"'
    dfsradmin membership list /rgname:$group
```