# Running msdeploy.exe from within Powershell

Tags: powershell, msdeploy

I'm trying to run the following command from within Powershell:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:archiveDir=c:\KitchenPC\Build -dest:appHostConfig="KitchenPC",computerName=https://192.168.0.3:8172/msdeploy.axd,authType=Basic,userName=someuser,password="secret" -allowUntrusted
```

The [docs say](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569106%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to simply substitute the `:` after each parameter with an `=`.  So I've tried this:

```
msdeploy -verb=sync -source=archiveDir=c:\KitchenPC\Build -dest=appHostConfig="KitchenPC",computerName=https://192.168.0.3:8172/msdeploy.axd,authType=Basic,userName=someuser,password="secret" -allowUntrusted
```

However, I get the error:

> Error: Unrecognized argument
>   'computerName=https://192.168.0.3:8172/msdeploy.axd'. All arguments
>   must begin with "-". Error count: 1.

I've checked the [docs on provider settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569001%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), however they have no mention of their equivelent Powershell syntax.

Comment: Or consider using [Web Deploy PowerShell Cmdlets](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-powershell-cmdlets).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[How do you call msdeploy from powershell when the parameters have spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499699/how-do-you-call-msdeploy-from-powershell-when-the-parameters-have-spaces)

Think this is already answered, just modify it.
Ex. include "KitchenPC" and "secret" using variables, and put the -dest part inside quotation marks.

**Working Example:**

```
msdeploy '-verb=sync' '-source=archiveDir=c:\KitchenPC\Build -dest=appHostConfig="KitchenPC",computerName=https://192.168.0.3:8172/msdeploy.axd,authType=Basic,userName=someuser,password="secret"' -allowUntrusted
```

(Note single quotes around each command line argument)

Comment: Yea, I read that post already.  They weren't using any provider settings, so it doesn't really apply.  The solution in the blog post was basically writing a function that spawns `cmd.exe` which might be the best solution.  That's too bad.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying.  [this post](http://forums.iis.net/p/1163388/1928386.aspx) helped me figure it out, and I've updated a working example to your answer.

Comment: Fantastic! So many other blog posts and responses say it's not possible or recommend kludges such as calling cmd or start-process.