# How to run iis backup executable in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run the following command and have tried passing arguments and hash tables but it did not work:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:metakey=lm/w3svc/1 -dest:package=C:\iis_backups\site1.zip,encryptPassword=xyxyz > C:\iis_backups\site1.log
```

Comment: Define `did not work` - what are you expecting it to do, and what is it doing instead. If you get an error message, please include the full message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered before here: [Running msdeploy.exe from within Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993278/running-msdeploy-exe-from-within-powershell)

It appears the solution for your scenario is as follows:

```
msdeploy.exe '-verb:sync' '-source:metakey=lm/w3svc/1' '-dest:package=C:\iis_backups\site1.zip,encryptPassword=xyxyz' > C:\iis_backups\site1.log
```