# Error running PackageWeb Powershell script from TeamCity build

Tags: c#, powershell, teamcity, msdeploy

I'm getting an error I'm baffled by when running a Powershell script in a TeamCity build. The script comes from a Nuget package called [PackageWeb](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PackageWeb/). The script is meant to take a MSDeploy package and deploy it to an instance of IIS running on a remote machine. The script can be read [here](https://github.com/sayedihashimi/package-web/blob/master/src/Publish-Interactive.ps1). The error I get is the following:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync
 -source:archiveDir="C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\App Name.csproj_zip" -
dest:auto,includeAcls='False',
ComputerName='mycomputer',Username=hurry,Password=up,AuthType='NTML' 
-disableLink:AppPoolExtension 
-disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension 
-setParamFile:"C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\App Name.csproj_zip\SetParameters.xml" -whatif -
skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="_Deploy_" -
skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=web\..*\.config -skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath=_Package 
-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=.*\.wpp\.targets$ -allowUntrusted -enableRule:DoNotDelete 

The term 'C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\App' is not recognized as the name 
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

The second line has to be the culprit, and the space between words in "App Name" is probably at fault, but I haven't found a way to escape this properly. The "App Name" is gotten from the zip file name of the msdeploy package (it's called "App Name.csproj_zip").

Any idea why Powershell run from TeamCity doesn't allow for a space in the path to msdeploy???

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499699/how-do-you-call-msdeploy-from-powershell-when-the-parameters-have-spaces/12813048#12813048

Comment: Thanks David, yeah, I tried most of the things mentioned there, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have been messing with Powershell+MSDeploy+TeamCity and following function works for me. Note that parameter {3} is the path to MSDeploy ( which contains spaces)

```
function Deploy([string]$server, [string]$remotePath, [string]$localPath) {
        $msdeploy = "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe";
        cmd.exe /C $("`"{3}`" -verb:sync -source:contentPath=`"{0}`" -dest:computerName=`"{1}`",contentPath=`"{2}`" " -f $localPath, $server, $remotePath , $msdeploy )
    }
```