# Migrating IIS 6 to IIS 7 with Web Deploy in Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm banging my head on this one.  So want to migrate our entire IIS 6 server (dozens of sites) over to a brand new IIS 7 server using the Web Deploy tool in powershell... Here is what I've tried:

```
.\msdeploy -verb=sync -source=webserver=computername=$oldserver -dest=webserver=computername=$newserver
```

And I'm getting:
Total changes: 0 (0 added, 0 deleted, 0 updated, 0 parameters changed, 0 bytes copied)

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you have spaces in you command.
This should work

```
$MSDEPLOY_EXE = "${env:ProgramFiles}\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe"
&($MSDEPLOY_EXE) -verb:sync -source:webserver=computername=$oldserver -dest:webserver=computername=$newserver
```

I realize that the instructions are to replace a `:` with a `=` in Powershell but that is not correct in all cases. When you use the `&` sign you can call `msdeploy` as you would in the command prompt.

See here for more information [How do you call msdeploy from powershell when the parameters have spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499699/how-do-you-call-msdeploy-from-powershell-when-the-parameters-have-spaces)